# How does boost::ptr_vector deep copy the underlying objects?

Tags: c++

`ptr_vector` is copy constructible and copy assignable. How can it deep copy the underlying objects when it doesn't know their concrete types?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `boost::ptr_vector` container has an optional template parameter, `CloneAllocator`, that defines the cloning policy.  The default allocator is the `heap_clone_allocator`, which simply invokes the copy constructor to clone an object.

The Clone Allocator is used as a way to add a layer of indirection around the cloning.  For example, it allows you to provide a custom allocator that correctly handles cloning of a noncopyable type.

You can find more information in [the Boost Pointer Containers Library documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/reference.html), which explains the Clonable and Clone Allocator concepts.

Comment: Ah -- so I need to support the clonable concept even if my object is copy-constructable? The docs seem to mention only clonable when the object is not.

Comment: @Billy:  That's my understanding of it.  I've not used `ptr_vector` extensively, but that is how other pointer containers I've used handle cloning.

Comment: @Billy: You can also use `view_clone_allocator` instead of `heap_clone_allocator` to get around the clonable requirement. Then no overload for `new_clone()` is needed. Obviously you cannot deep-copy containers then.