# Copying a vector of pointers

Tags: c++

I have a `std::vector<A*>` which I need to deep copy to another vector using `A::Clone()`.

Instead of using handwritten loops, I was wondering whether I could use `for_each` or any Standard Library algorithm for this.

Comment: What is the vector declaration ? Is it of pointers ?

Comment: @iammilind: Yes. He failed to format his code properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The appropriate algorithm is [std::transform](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) and you can turn member function invocation into a unary functor with [std::mem_fun](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/mem_fun/)

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

class X
{
public:
    X* clone();
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<X*> vec1, vec2;
    std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), std::back_inserter(vec2), std::mem_fun(&X::clone));
}
```

If the target vector is already the same size as the input range, you can pass `vec2.begin()` as the third argument. Use `back_inserter` if the target is empty (or you want to append to it).

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this would work:

```
class DeepCopy {
public:
    A* operator() (A* aP) {
        return aP->Clone();
    }
}

int main() 
{
    vector<A*> vA;
    vector<A*> vA2;

    transform(vA.begin(), vA.end(), back_inserter(vA2), DeepCopy());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `boost::ptr_vector<A>` instead of `std::vector<A*>`.

[This has a template parameter `CloneAllocator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428907/how-does-boostptr-vector-deep-copy-the-underlying-objects), for which you could pass the relevant custom cloner.

Comment: He is looking for a solution based on the standard library.

Comment: @Vijay: Regardless, this is a valid, pre-existing approach. If he said "standard library" only in the sense of "not having to hand-write a loop", then this answer is appropriate. If he really only wants standard library solutions (why? Boost is free) then he can feel free to look at a different one!