# c++ boost clone ptr vector

Tags: c++, boost, vector, pointers

I am having difficulties with copying a ptr_vector.

I am using a solution class which has a vector of Act objects.
Inside each Act class I have a ptr_vector which links back to other Act objects .
I read in some data from a txt file and I store it in an Sol object. Now how can I copy this Sol object to other Sol objects (for example in a vector). I tried writing my own copy constructor in the sol class using release and clone but its seems the ptr_vector cannot be copied so easily.

Thanks in advance.

```
class Sol
{
 public:
//data
int obj;
vector<Act*> deficit_act;
int deadline;
int nbr_res;
int nbr_act;
std::vector<Act> act;
std::vector<Res> res;
}

#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
#include <boost/ptr_container/clone_allocator.hpp>
class Act
{
public:
//static
int id;
int es;//earliest start
int ls;//latest start
int range;//difference between ls and es
int dur;//duration of the activity
std::vector<int> dem;//demand requirement for every resource: needs to be      initiliased
//predecessors and successors
int nrpr;
int nrsu;
boost::ptr_vector<Act> pr;
boost::ptr_vector<Act> su;
//dynamic
int start;
int end;
Act():id(-1),es(0),ls(0),range(0),dur(0),nrpr(0),nrsu(0),start(-1),end(-1){}
~Act(){}
    };

   //inside the main.cpp
    Sol emptysol;
read_instance(emptysol,instance_nr,"J301_1");
emptysol.calc_parameters();
vector<Sol> sol;
sol.reserve(pop_size);
for(int ind=0;ind<pop_size;++ind)
{
    sol.push_back(Sol(emptysol));// this throws a stack overflow error
}
```

Comment: Did you get the stack overflow when you tried your own Sol copy constructor? If so, where's the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you get a stack overflow error suggests that the copy constructor or push_back starts an infinite recursion. The way that this can happen in your case is if the `pr` and `su` pointer vectors of your `Act` objects contain a cycle. Which would mean you get this error if you try to copy construct a `Sol` object with non-empty `Act` vectors where the `Act` objects in those vectors contain a cycle.

Just to make this clear: copy constructors of ptr_vectors will make a copy ('Clone' in ptr_vector language) of the objects pointed to. If the `su` member would point back to the Act object which owns it (directly or indirectly) you'd start an infinite recursion.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428907/how-does-boostptr-vector-deep-copy-the-underlying-objects) SO question goes into the details of ptr_vector copy constructors.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have a cycle indeed as the predecessor(pr) of the successor(su) of act is the act itself. I have no copy problems when I only use either pr or su. But how can I implement the cycles with pointers as i really need this relationship.

Comment: pointer_vectors are not suited for this, since they act like 'value' containers and only use pointers to allow polymorphism. A better choice would be a vector of shared_ptrs, but in that case you also need to break any cycles, because cycles of shared pointers will not be deleted.

Comment: Breaking cycles is normally application specific. If you can guarantee that predessors outlive successors, you could use raw pointers for the predecessors.