# Create Deep copy of boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, shared-ptr

I have two vectors of shared_ptr;

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr <A> someptr;
std::vector<someptr>src;
std::vector<someptr>dest;
```

If I copy using dest=src,both the vector elements are sharing the same memory location which increases the ref count of pointer.They both point to common location and any change in elements of one vector will affect the other.I understood that this is a shallow copy and it is the intended behaviour.

But if I want to create a deep copy for dest vector elements with different memory location ,what should I do?How to achieve this?

Does boost have a function to achieve this?

Comment: Do your vectors only contain instances of `A`, or also of classes derived from it?

Comment: For ex: src contains 2 elements.dest is a new empty vector which needs a deep copy.They dont have derived classes.

Comment: `for (auto const& p : src) dest.push_back(make_shared<A>(*p));`

Comment: Eljay's solution will only work if the vector can't contain classes derived from A. If it can, you'll need something else.

Comment: using the above code statement throws error:showing cannot convert boost::shared_ptr<A> to (const A&).

Comment: Add `@username` to your comments to notify the user you're talking to, otherwise they might not get a notification and might never reply. You're always getting notifications because the comments are under your question.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Simplest:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct T {};

int main() {
    std::vector<T> a{100};
    auto b = a; // deep copy all T
}
```

Of course, there will be a reason why you had the `shared_ptr`. E.g. when the objects aren't movable and/or runtime polymorphic.

---

### Enter Pointer Container

Boost Pointer Container satisfies this need. It allows you to customize the way in which elements should be cloned (see e.g. [How does boost::ptr_vector deep copy the underlying objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428907/how-does-boostptr-vector-deep-copy-the-underlying-objects) or [the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/reference.html)).

Simple example: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/142bae389c071b09)**

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() = default; // runtime polymorphic
  virtual char const* foo() const = 0;
};

struct T : Base {
  virtual char const* foo() const override { return "T"; }
};
struct U : Base {
  virtual char const* foo() const override { return "U"; }
};

static inline Base* new_clone(Base const& obj) {
    if (auto* p = dynamic_cast<T const*>(&obj))
        return new T{*p};
    if (auto* p = dynamic_cast<U const*>(&obj))
        return new U{*p};
    return nullptr;
}

int main() {
    boost::ptr_vector<Base> a;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(a), 5, [] { return new T{}; });
    // polymorphic
    a.insert(a.begin()+2, new U{});

    auto b = a; // deep copy all elements, derived from Base

    // not sharing the instances:
    assert(&a.front() != &b.front());

    std::cout << "\na:";
    for (auto& el : a) std::cout << " " << el.foo(); 

    std::cout << "\nb:";
    for (auto& el : b) std::cout << " " << el.foo(); 
}
```

Prints

```
a: T T U T T T
b: T T U T T T
```

---

### `std::vector<unique_ptr>`

This is conceptually similar, but requires more work by you:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe5cb0ef0959f3a4)**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() = default; // runtime polymorphic
  virtual char const* foo() const = 0;
};

struct T : Base {
  virtual char const* foo() const override { return "T"; }
};
struct U : Base {
  virtual char const* foo() const override { return "U"; }
};

struct Cloner {
    using Ptr = std::unique_ptr<Base>;
    Ptr operator()(Ptr const& pb) const {
        if (auto* p = dynamic_cast<T const*>(pb.get()))
            return std::make_unique<T>(*p);
        if (auto* p = dynamic_cast<U const*>(pb.get()))
            return std::make_unique<U>(*p);
        return nullptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base> > a;
    a.push_back(std::make_unique<T>());
    a.push_back(std::make_unique<U>());
    a.push_back(std::make_unique<T>());

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base> > b;

    // deep copy all elements, derived from Base
    Cloner clone;
    std::transform(begin(a), end(a), back_inserter(b), clone);

    // not sharing the instances:
    assert(&*a.front() != &*b.front());

    std::cout << "\na:";
    for (auto& p : a) std::cout << " " << p->foo(); 

    std::cout << "\nb:";
    for (auto& p : b) std::cout << " " << p->foo(); 
}
```

Prints:

```
a: T U T
b: T U T
```

### `vector<unique_ptr>` but "easier"?

If you like you can use some "magic" to make that simpler:

- Using Boost Range

  **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3fab41991e30110)**

  ```
    // deep copy all elements, derived from Base
    auto b = boost::copy_range<upvec>(a | transformed(Cloner{}));
  ```
- Using standard ranges (c++20)

  Using  Ranges v3 instead because `to_vector` hasn't been standardized (yet)

  **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/p6JF9U)**

  ```
    // deep copy all elements, derived from Base
    auto b = ranges::to_vector(a | ranges::views::transform(Cloner{}));
  ```

---

### Fully automatic: [Boost PolyCollection](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/poly_collection.html)

This doesn't retain order, but it has the advantage that you don't have to come up with the cloning logic, and you can do smart iteration by type etc.:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f4a30691a6f8551)**

```
#include <boost/poly_collection/base_collection.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() = default; // runtime polymorphic
  virtual char const* foo() const = 0;
};

struct T : Base {
  virtual char const* foo() const override { return "T"; }
};
struct U : Base {
  virtual char const* foo() const override { return "U"; }
};

int main() {
    using C = boost::poly_collection::base_collection<Base>;
    
    C a;
    a.insert(T{});
    a.insert(U{});
    a.insert(T{});

    // deep copy all elements, derived from Base
    auto b = a;

    // not sharing the instances:
    assert(&*a.begin() != &*b.begin());

    std::cout << "\na:";
    for (auto& p : a) std::cout << " " << p.foo(); 

    std::cout << "\nb:";
    for (auto& p : b) std::cout << " " << p.foo(); 
}
```

Prints

```
a: U T T
b: U T T
```

Comment: Fleshed out three alternatives: [ptr_vector](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/142bae389c071b09), [vector<unique_ptr<Base>>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe5cb0ef0959f3a4), [boost::poly_collection<Base>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f4a30691a6f8551). Only the latter does the cloning completely for you.

Comment: ,Thanku so much for sharing the code.In fact the two vector objects I have are of the same class and one not derived from the other.Whenever u make a copy as b=a ,it results in shallow copy.I need a deep copy or copy by value from a to b.Using the copy constructor to copy b from a( b(*a)),does throw an error.

Comment: Can you **show** the problem have (maybe by editing the live samples?). I don't get what you mean.

Comment: In all my approaches the copied vectors are the same type, thre copies are deep and they all compile without error.